# How to apply an action refiner to all requests sent to a SIRD Router?

Tags: scala, playframework, routes

Let's say I have this SIRD Router:

```
val adminRouter = Router.from {
  case GET(p"/posts") =>
    Action { implicit request =>
      ...
    }
}
```

And this Action Refiner:

```
object NameSpace {
  class SecuredRequest[A](val username: String, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

  def securedAction(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = new ActionRefiner[Request, SecuredRequest] {
    def executionContext: ExecutionContext = ec

    def refine[A](request: Request[A]): Future[Either[Result, SecuredRequest[A]]] = {
      val username = request.session.get("username")

      if (username.isDefined)
        Future.successful(Right(new SecuredRequest(username.get, request)))
      else
        Future.successful(Left(Results.Redirect(controllers.routes.AuthController.signInUser())))
    }
  }
}
```

Then in my `conf/routes` file I have this

```
->   /admin   adminRouter
```

What I would like is to apply the `securedAction` **action refiner** to all requests sent to the `adminRouter` before they get to it. So the `adminRouter` will just assume that all requests have a `username` field if they managed to get to him.

Do I Have to create a `SecuredAction` **action builder** and use it to create action like this ?

```
case GET(p"/posts") =>
  SecuredAction { implicit request =>
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass `SecuredRequest`s to your handler function, yes, you have to define an ActionBuilder as you said, since the ActionBuilder used determines the type of the parameter given to the action block.

```
// note the `R` type parameter
trait ActionBuilder[+R[_], B] extends ActionFunction[Request, R] {
  final def apply(block: R[B] => Result): Action[B] = ...
}
```

The default action builder you get in a controller, is an `ActionBuilder[Request, AnyContent]`. So the parameter given to the block is fixed to be some kind of Request.

If you use such an action builder and call the `apply(block: R[B] => Result): Action[B]` (or any other of its overloaded friends) you simply get an `Action[B]` (basically an `EssentialAction` with a parser) and you have no chance changing the block parameter type afterwards.

Comment: OK I see. I hoped that there were a possibility to refine request at the Router level. The issue with this approach is that if you change your mine later about which handler need to be secured or not you need to go down to each handler. I am coming from NodeJS where you can apply a Middleware per router too, I was just looking for the same possibility. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way this could have been possible if this an Action could return another Router, and if Routers could do partial pattern matching against the RequestHeader.

Something like this:

```
val adminRouter = Router.from {
  case GET(p"/api/$subPath") =>
    SecuredAction { implicit request: SecuredRequest =>

      Router.from {
        subPath match {
          case p"posts" => {
            Action { implicit request: SecuredRequest =>
              ...
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

But it is not supported yet.